# Value change jQuery listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need an alert to pop up when the value of the input is changed by jQuery.

Currently it only pops an alert dialog when I type into the textbox but not when I press <kbd>CLICK</kbd>.

```js
$("#c1").on('input', function() {
  alert("value changed");
});

$("#c1").find("button").click(function() {
  $("#c1").find('input').val("hello");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="c1">
  <div class="input-group col-lg-2">
    <span class="input-group-addon">   
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i>   
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">   
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">CLICK</button>   
    </span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Use on(keyup) or keydown event

Answer (score 0):

Add `.trigger('input')` to your button click handler:

```
$("#c1").find("button").click(function(){   
  $("#c1").find('input').val("hello").trigger('input');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zqac3gfj/)**

```js
$("#c1").on('input', function() {
  alert("value changed");
});

$("#c1").find("button").click(function(){  
  $("#c1").find('input').val("hello").trigger('input');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="c1">
  <div class="input-group col-lg-2">
    <span class="input-group-addon">   
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i>   
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">   
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">CLICK</button>   
    </span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding right try this:

```
$("input.form-control").keyup(function(){
    $(this).trigger('change');
});
$("input.form-control").change(function() {
  alert("value changed");
});
```

Or you can shorten a little to this:

```
$("input.form-control").keyup(function(){
    $(this).trigger('change');
}).change(function() {
    alert("value changed.\r\nNew Value: "+$(this).val());
});
```

[JSFiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/dkaufmanjs/yL9c9bzd/1/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to trigger the alert dialog when the Click button is pressed to change the value of the input box.

Comment: The question was to have "an alert to pop up when the value of the input is changed".  When the value is CHANGED the alert pops.  This is exactly what the question asked for.  If this is not what you're after please change your question.

Comment: What exactly are you after here?  Your question is more than a little vague.  If you just want it on the click then `$("button").click(function(){ alert('boom'); });` will do that.  Do you want this on a submit? On input blur? What is the purpose of clicking the button?